# How can I compare and return data using a list of data

Tags: haskell, ghci, winghci

I'm a newbie to Haskell and I'm struggling to find a way to use class member variables to return the member variable I am looking for. I have this data:

```
 data Place = Place {name :: String, 
                north :: Float, 
                east :: Float, 
                rainfall :: [Int]
                } deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

 testData :: [Place]
 testData = [
        Place "London"     51.5  (-0.1)  [0, 0, 5, 8, 8, 0, 0],
        Place "Norwich"    52.6  (1.3)   [0, 6, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3],
        Place "Birmingham" 52.5  (-1.9)  [0, 2, 10, 7, 8, 2, 2],
        Place "Hull"       53.8  (-0.3)  [0, 6, 5, 0, 0, 0, 4],
        Place "Newcastle"  55.0  (-1.6)  [0, 0, 8, 3, 6, 7, 5],
        Place "Aberdeen"   57.1  (-2.1)  [0, 0, 6, 5, 8, 2, 0],
        Place "St Helier"  49.2  (-2.1)  [0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 10, 0]
        ]
```

What I'm trying to do is to return a place closest to a given location. So far I am able to calculate the distances for each place to the given location, and I know exactly which Item should be returned, but I don't know how to actually go about doing this. This is the code I have so far;

```
closestDry :: Float -> Float -> [Place] -> [Float]
closestDry _ _ [] = []
closestDry lx ly (x:xs) = distance(lx)(ly)(north x)(east x)):closestDry lx ly xs

distance :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Float -> Float
distance x1 y1 x2 y2 = sqrt ((y1 - y2)^2 + (x1 - x2)^2)
```

Typing into the console 'closestDry 51.5 (-0.1) testData' outputs:

```
[0.0,1.7804484,2.059126,2.3086786,3.8078866,5.946426,3.0479496]
```

I can see that the closest area must be "London" in order with the given list of places as the distance is '0.0', but how do I get this single Place returned to me?

I don't want to return the list of distances, but I can't figure out how to tell the function to get the smallest distance and return that corresponding Place, since it needs to be compared to the other places.

Comment: Nitpick: your `distance` function calculates Euclidean distance, which isn't actually right for longitude and latitude coordinates, since the Earth isn't flat. You should replace it with a function that calculates great-circle distance (and if you want to be really picky, also account for the Earth being an oblate spheroid and not a perfect sphere).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`closestDry` is a basically-useless mess, so get rid of it. Then, let's write a `distanceTo` function that gives you the distance from coordinates to a place:

```
distanceTo :: Float -> Float -> Place -> Float
distanceTo lat lon place = distance lat lon (north place) (east place)
```

Now, let's write a function that pairs the places with the distances to them:

```
distancesTo :: Float -> Float -> [Place] -> [(Place, Float)]
distancesTo lat lon = map (\place -> (place, distanceTo lat lon place))
```

Trying it out:

```
λ> distancesTo 51.5 (-0.1) testData
[(Place {name = "London", north = 51.5, east = -0.1, rainfall = [0,0,5,8,8,0,0]},0.0),(Place {name = "Norwich", north = 52.6, east = 1.3, rainfall = [0,6,5,0,0,0,3]},1.7804484),(Place {name = "Birmingham", north = 52.5, east = -1.9, rainfall = [0,2,10,7,8,2,2]},2.059126),(Place {name = "Hull", north = 53.8, east = -0.3, rainfall = [0,6,5,0,0,0,4]},2.3086786),(Place {name = "Newcastle", north = 55.0, east = -1.6, rainfall = [0,0,8,3,6,7,5]},3.8078866),(Place {name = "Aberdeen", north = 57.1, east = -2.1, rainfall = [0,0,6,5,8,2,0]},5.946426),(Place {name = "St Helier", north = 49.2, east = -2.1, rainfall = [0,0,0,0,6,10,0]},3.0479496)]
```

Looks right so far!

Now we can use `minimumBy`, `comparing`, and `snd` to get the tuple, and then extract just the place with `fst`:

```
import Data.Foldable (minimumBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

closestTo :: Float -> Float -> [Place] -> Place
closestTo lat lon places = fst $ minimumBy (comparing snd) (distancesTo lat lon places)
```

Let's try it:

```
λ> closestTo 51.5 (-0.1) testData
Place {name = "London", north = 51.5, east = -0.1, rainfall = [0,0,5,8,8,0,0]}
```

Success!

---

As an alternative to having `distancesTo`, you could also calculate the distances with `comparing`, like this:

```
closestTo :: Float -> Float -> [Place] -> Place
closestTo lat lon places = minimumBy (comparing (distanceTo lat lon)) places
```

This has the advantage of not needing any of the tuples, but the disadvantage of recomputing the distance for the same place multiple times.

---

Caveat to either way: `minimumBy` is a dangerous partial function, which will crash your program if it ever gets an empty list, which will happen if `closestTo` gets an empty list:

```
λ> closestTo 51.5 (-0.1) []
*** Exception: Prelude.foldl1: empty list
```

If you care about that, you'd need to avoid it by returning a `Maybe Place` instead, and adjusting the code to return `Nothing` when the input list is empty, instead of calling `minimumBy`. (IMO, this is a wart in Haskell, and `minimumBy` should just return a `Maybe` itself instead of having to crash.)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is a very smart way to do this. I'll definitely be using methods like this in the future and really appreciate your help!