# Writing a function which needs to find the closest place to coordinates given in, through haskell

Tags: haskell

I started this function as follows:

```
type Place = (String, Float, Float, [Int])
distanceList :: Float -> Float-> [Place] -> [Float]
distanceList _ _ [] = []
distanceList degN degE ((location, float1, float2, rainfall):place) =
sqrt((float1-degN)^2 + (float2-degE)^2) : distanceList degN degE place


minDistance :: Float -> Float-> Float -> Float -> [Float] -> Float
minDistance _ _ _ _ [] = 0
minDistance degN degE float1 float2 (x:xs)
    | x < minDistance degN degE float1 float2 xs = x
    | otherwise = minDistance degN degE float1 float2 xs



closestPlace :: Float -> Float -> [Place] -> String
closestPlace _ _ [] = " An error as occured "
closestPlace degN degE ((location, float1,  float2, rainfall):place)
    | rainfall !!0 == 0 && pythag == distance = location
    | otherwise = closestPlace degN degE place
    where
        pythag = sqrt((float1-degN)^2 + (float2-degE)^2)
        distance = minDistance degN degE float1 float2 (distanceList 
        degN degE place)
```

i have test data which is passed through the Place. and the two floats are coordinates north and east, i need to use Pythagoras theorem to return a single String of which location is closest.

The code above runs but when thee closestPlace function runs it never gets passed the first part which is the error message, i just need the function to compare the Pythagorus output of the two functions above to and print the string of the location which is closest to the coordinates inputted.

the code to run this is as follows:

```
 demo :: Int -> IO ()
 demo 7 = putStrLn (closestPlace 55.0 (-5.3) testData)
```

Comment: What code have you written for this, and what's not working? As it stands there's no actual question here.

Comment: I have just updated it to show the code i have written :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I compare and return data using a list of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61262801/how-can-i-compare-and-return-data-using-a-list-of-data)

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty much there. As far as calculating the distance goes, one observation can be made:

> If the distance to point A is greater than the distance to point B, the square of distance to A will be greater than the square of the distance to B.

This means that instead of comparing distances (and computing a square root unnecessarily), we can compare squares of them, which are calculated like so:

```
dist2 x1 y1 x2 y2 = (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2
```

However, you also want to extract some additional metadata. Two common approaches are appending the sorting key and stripping it after, or using the comparison function directly. Here, the second approach will work quite well:

```
closestPlace :: Float -> Float -> [Place] -> Place
closestPlace x y = minimumBy (comparing (dist2P x y))
```

I've added a helper here called `dist2P` that allows us to compare a pair of points to a place directly; this is convenient, because we can then use `comparing` to automatically apply that on a pair of points that is then used by `minimumBy` to find the closest point.

```
dist2P :: Float -> Float -> Place -> Float
dist2P x y (_, x', y', _) = dist x y x' y'
```

That helper then gets partially applied with the source point.

Thanks to `minimumBy` we're also able to eta-reduce `closestPlace`, which is always nice.

And finally, I've decided to change the signature of your function to return `Place` instead of `String`. Why? Well, if it turns out you need any other information from the place, you can easily access it with a getter like so:

```
placeName :: Place -> String
placeName (s, _, _, _) = s
```

And similarly, your original function would thus be implemented as a composition of the two:

```
closestPlaceName :: Float -> Float -> [Place] -> String
closestPlaceName x y = placeName . closestPlace x y
```

Comment: hey, the code i had already written is now above, I was thinking of keeping along those lines, i dont know what ive written works properly but that was the sort of way i was doing it. is there anything that i could change with that code that would work or is it just nonsense code?

Comment: Thank you so much managed to figure it out, i was just getting confused cause i never thought of doing it this way, many thanks :)

Comment: One more question actually, if i wanted to filter so the rainfall (list of Ints) the first element had to be 0, which function would i put this clause in? so say i only want the location closest that has zero rain yesterday which is the first element in the rainfall list.

Comment: @SamParsons Filter before putting it in your search function: `closestPlace x y . filter (firstElement0) $ allPlaces`

Comment: @ Bartek Banachewicz, hey, for some reason this isnt working for me, do i need to import anything?

Comment: @SamParsons `comparing`?